# how to display alphabet index corresponding listview in andorid

Tags: android, listview

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    String result;

    Point p;
    Map<String, Integer> mapIndex;

    String URL = "http://www.taxmann.com/TaxmannWhatsnewService/mobileservice.aspx?service=topstories";
    ArrayList<DataModel> list = new ArrayList<DataModel>();
    JSONArray _jarray1;

    String ImagePath;
    ListView fruitList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btn_show = (Button) findViewById(R.id.show_popup);

        btn_show.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                // Open popup window
                if (p != null)
                    // new download().execute();

                    showPopup(MainActivity.this, p);

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {

        int[] location = new int[2];
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.show_popup);
        button.getLocationOnScreen(location);
        p = new Point();
        p.x = location[0];
        p.y = location[1];
    }

    // The method that displays the popup.
    private void showPopup(final Activity context, Point p) {

        LinearLayout viewGroup = (LinearLayout) context
                .findViewById(R.id.popup);
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, viewGroup);

        // Creating the PopupWindow
        final PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(context);
        popup.setContentView(layout);
        popup.setWidth(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        popup.setHeight(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        popup.setFocusable(true);

        int OFFSET_X = 30;
        int OFFSET_Y = 30;
        fruitList = (ListView) layout.findViewById(R.id.list_fruits);
        // Clear the default translucent background
        popup.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());

        // Displaying the popup at the specified location, + offsets.
        popup.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, p.x + OFFSET_X, p.y
                + OFFSET_Y);

        new download().execute();
        List<DataModel> arrlist = new ArrayList<DataModel>();

        String[] stringArray = arrlist.toArray(new String[list.size()]);

        getIndexList(stringArray);

        LinearLayout indexLayout = (LinearLayout) layout
                .findViewById(R.id.side_index);

        TextView textView;
        List<String> indexList = new ArrayList<String>(mapIndex.keySet());
        for (String index : indexList) {
            textView = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                    R.layout.side_index_item, null);
            textView.setText(index);
            textView.setOnClickListener(this);
            indexLayout.addView(textView);
        }
    }

    private void getIndexList(String[] fruits) {
        mapIndex = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {

            String fruit = fruits[i];
            String index = fruit.substring(0, 1);

            if (mapIndex.get(index) == null)
                mapIndex.put(index, i);
        }
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        TextView selectedIndex = (TextView) view;
        fruitList.setSelection(mapIndex.get(selectedIndex.getText()));
    }

    class download extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {
                result = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(URL);
                _jarray1 = new JSONArray(result);

                for (int i = 0; i < _jarray1.length(); i++) {
                    DataModel datamodel = new DataModel();
                    JSONObject _obj = _jarray1.getJSONObject(i);
                    ImagePath = _obj.getString("news_title");
                    if (ImagePath != null) {
                        datamodel.setImagepath(_obj.getString("news_title"));

                        Log.e("Valueeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee",
                                "IMAGE PATHAAAAAAAAAAAA: "
                                        + _obj.getString("news_title"));

                    }
                    list.add(datamodel);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            CustomList adapter = new CustomList(MainActivity.this, list);
            fruitList.setAdapter(adapter);

            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }

}
```

This is my code am trying to display alphabetically Index corresponding list-view corresponding list-view like when i click on Index t then list scroll to view where t data is coming basically i want alphabetically search from List  i am to display Listview on popup but i unable to display Index from which we search  please suggest me where am doing wrong i am getting blank data when i tring to Convert list to String array of DataModel please suggest me where  i am doing wrong and tell me Solution

Comment: Would that tutorial help you? http://androidopentutorials.com/android-listview-with-alphabetical-side-index/

Comment: This example i have allredy done but i am having Problem to fetch data from web service and then convert list to stringarray so that i can get Index  @NicolasSimon

Comment: Then it's a totally different problem than what you're asking here :/

Comment: i want to  do same thing but i am facing Problem to show alphabet in right side corresponding index

Comment: See this https://github.com/woozzu/IndexableListView or http://www.brightec.co.uk/blog/android-listview-alphabet-scroller

Answer (score 0):

I hope these will help you man!!!!

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        Collections.sort(list);
        CustomList adapter = new CustomList(MainActivity.this, list);
        fruitList.setAdapter(adapter);
         super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
```

Happy coding......